# How do i deduct a percentage from a number and assign the difference to the innerHTML attribute using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im customizing a payment gateway solution using php and jquery. Before i pass the data(ie. customer address, tele, amount of purchase, etc.), I want to deduct 2.9% from the purchase/product amount.(which would be my personal service fee) and then pass the remaining balance to the payment gateway for processing. How would i do this using PHP?

```
var $adjustedamount;
var $mypercentage = 0.029;

function computemypercentage($original_price){

$adjustedamount =  ($original_price += ($original_price * $mypercentage)); 
return $adjustedamount;
}
document.getElementById("trueamount").innerHTML= computemypercentage(29.99);
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have right now?

Comment: Oh for the love of god please do not do this in JavaScript!!! Or... at least tell me where your site is so I can ensure I get a really great discount :)

Comment: Money= server-side. It's just a matter of right clicking and you can hack anything on the front-end, so unless you are using javascript on the server, don't do this

Comment: For some odd reason, the remaining value is not being assigned to the innHTML property. I thought it was something wrong i was doing in my function.

Comment: lol. Thanks Josh..  wasn't sure what technology should be used..

Comment: In all seriousness... you are on the right track, but **PLEASE** do not rely on the value you are computing here for **ANYTHING!!!** It is ok for display purposes to let the customer know what they will be getting charged, but never under any circumstances use values computed on the client for something as important as money.

Comment: Well.. obviously the question has become, how do i do this in php lol?

Comment: @NicelyDone32 - It's not that you can't do this in javascript to show the user what is going to happen, but when they post the form to your server, you need to do the calculation there. The only values you should care about are the user input values. Values concerning money should be retrieved server side and used to do the computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in the comments already, please ensure **ANY** calculations about money are done on the server side. JavaScript is great for providing a better user experience, but not for critical business logic.

The reason for this is that it is simply too easy to modify those values. Pull up any modern browser and open the developer tools. You can change form values and JavaScript at will, making anything coming from the client untrustworthy by default.

As for assigning the value to some element... your code should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yPC3K/